# big query stream input does not work

Tags: google-bigquery

at the moment i can't import data to big query by streaming data to bigquery. The application works without any error but there an no new data in the corresponding table.

does anyone have the same problem?

thanks.
Marcel

Comment: For us is working now, so it's not a global problem. Any error you get?

Comment: any reference to work with? project number? job id?

Comment: yes my own stupidity. looks like my mistake of a wrong handled error condition of the service.

Comment: don't be hard on yourself :)